# How can I get a handle on keyboard in vb net?

Tags: vb.net, keyboard, vb.net-2010, handle, createfile

This is my keyboard:

```
-----------------------------------
Win32_Keyboard instance
-----------------------------------
Availability:
Caption: Enhanced (101- or 102-key)
ConfigManagerErrorCode: 0
ConfigManagerUserConfig: False
CreationClassName: Win32_Keyboard
Description: Standard PS/2 Keyboard
DeviceID: ACPI\PNP0303\4&844A824&0
ErrorCleared:
ErrorDescription:
InstallDate:
IsLocked:
LastErrorCode:
Layout: 00000409
Name: Enhanced (101- or 102-key)
NumberOfFunctionKeys: 12
Password:
PNPDeviceID: ACPI\PNP0303\4&844A824&0
PowerManagementCapabilities:
PowerManagementSupported: False
Status: OK
StatusInfo:
SystemCreationClassName: Win32_ComputerSystem
```

I'm trying to get a handle using "CreateFile" which works for disks and should work for keyboard too.
So far no luck.
Any clues?

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: A keyboard cannot be opened with CreateFile().  The fake CONIN$ device name for a console input stream is the closest match, surely that's not what you mean.  Although it is entirely unclear what you exactly mean to do.

Comment: Do you want to laugh? I posted this question one year ago and I sincerely can't remember what I was up to.

Answer (score 0):

do you just want the handle?

Private Sub TextBox1_KeyDown(sender As Object, e As KeyEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyDown

```
    Dim hnd As IntPtr = sender.handle()

End Sub
```

Comment: I have more than one keyboard, how to get a specific keyboard handle? (or mouse as another example)